# Why is my switch statement running multiple cases?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have the following function:

```
$("#drpType").change(function () {
    var SelectedVal = this.value;
    switch (SelectedVal) {
        case "2021":
            console.log('a');
            console.log('b');
        case "2020":
            console.log('a');
        case "ADB":
            console.log('b');
        case "PWP":
            console.log('c');
    }
}
```

Why, when `SelectedVal` is 2021, is it printing `a,b,a,b,c`?

Created scenario in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sahirali/13g20vwx/). Now i am able to understand you my question. When select `2021` it return 2 divs. and if switch statement base on fall-thought so why its happning that if select `EFGH` the only one div visible instead of 3?

```
<select id="drpQuotaType" >
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>
  <option value="EFGH">EFGH</option>
</select>

<div id="dv1" style="display:none">Div 1 </div></br>
<div id="dv2" style="display:none">Div 2 </div></br>
<div id="dv3" style="display:none">Div 3 </div></br>
<div id="dv4" style="display:none">Div 4 </div>


$("#drpQuotaType").change(function () {
            var SelectedVal = this.value;
            $('#dv1').hide();
            $('#dv2').hide();
            $('#dv3').hide();
            switch (SelectedVal) {
                case "2021":
                    $('#dv1').show();
                    $('#dv2').show();
                case "2020":
                    $('#dv2').show();
                case "ABCD":
                    $('#dv2').show();
                case "EFGH":
                    $('#dv3').show();
            }

});
```

Comment: To those voting to close as a typographical error: It's only a typographical error if OP understands what `break` statements are for. When starting out, it's reasonable to think that you don't need `break` statements.

Comment: @MikeC yes make sense.Why need to break after each case.

Comment: If you rated both answers down, I'm sorry to say but they're right. Also, I agree with Mike C Some languages "fall through" without a break, other languages function like an if statement, following the path of the first success. It can confuse a person crossing between 'conflicting' styles.

Comment: This isn't a typographical error.  This is not knowing how to correctly implement a switch statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you don't have a `break` statement. Without it, the code will "fall through".

```js
var x = 10;
switch (x) {
  case 10:
    console.log('With break');
    break;
    
  case 20:
    console.log('I never run');
    break;
}

console.log('-------');

switch (x) {
  case 10:
    console.log('Without');
  case 20:
    console.log('a break');
  case 30:
    console.log('it just');
  case 40:
    console.log('keeps going');
}
```

The reason this exists is because sometimes it's useful to fall through. You could imagine a case where you're updating the state of a game and what stuff to happen for a specific kind of enemy as well as for all enemies.

```js
var characterType = 'big boss';

switch (characterType) {
  case 'big boss':
    console.log('Update the big boss');
  
  case 'enemy':
    console.log('The big boss is also an enemy so run the basic enemy code');
    break;
    
  case 'player':
    console.log('The boss is not a player so we will not run this.');
    break;
}
```

It's not incredibly common to utilize fall-through but it does have its use cases.

Finally, here's what your code should look like:

```
$("#drpType").change(function () {
    var SelectedVal = this.value;
    switch (SelectedVal) {
        case "2021":
            console.log('a');
            console.log('b');
            break; // <--

        case "2020":
            console.log('a');
            break; // <--

        case "ADB":
            console.log('b');
            break; // <--

        case "PWP":
            console.log('c');
            break; // optional. It's visually consistent but doesn't do anything
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain why you downvoted? This answers the question as it seems that OP doesn't understand what `break` statements are for.

Comment: Is there a reason that's any more preferential to `if enemy or big boss` with a nested `if big boss`? I ask because case fall-through has always seemed pretty purposeless to me. In order for your example to work, order of cases is very important.

Comment: @RegularJoe Sure, this case is very arbitrary. There are cases where you could have many values (imagine an enumerator that lists a bunch of possible numeric types vs. string types or something similar). Likewise, it may read better for your situation, especially if you have something that makes sense to fall through more than once. [Here are some good examples of fall-through use.](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116221/appropriate-uses-of-fall-through-switch-statements)

Answer (score 6):

You are missing your `break;` statements on each of your cases:

```
$("#drpType").change(function () {
    var SelectedVal = this.value;
    switch (SelectedVal) {
        case "2021":
            console.log('a');
            console.log('b');
            break;
        case "2020":
            console.log('a');
            break;
        case "ADB":
            console.log('b');
            break;
        case "PWP":
            console.log('c');
            break;
    }
```

Comment: @DanBeaulieu It was very likely the OP that downvoted both answers, as both immediately had a -1. In any case, there's no indication for the average user to know who downvoted.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu the -2 was done against him. You get a -1 for downvoting (edit: which is never shown to anyone else).

Comment: I stand corrected. Sorry for the confusion and for accusing you, I've re-applied my upvote. Thanks @RegularJoe for pointing out my error.